# <sheet>.setActiveRange() seems to have stopped working with onOpen trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am pretty sure (I can't site dates) that using the new sheets, the setActiveRange() method has been working. I had some scripts to take me to where I had left off in a big file. I had a corresponding script in Documents using the setCursor() method. Even though they're in no way related (or so it seems to me) they both seem to have stopped working, when triggered. They work fine invoked manually.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to a recent change that was documented in the [April 17th, 2014 release notes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/#april_17_2014).

Comment: There are technical reasons why this change was required. If there is sufficient demand we can look into re-enabling these use cases.

Comment: I'd like to register my own vote that it be restored. I use this to open an accounting spreadsheet to the first open line, and also a text document to the first blank row in a table. Is there some other way to accomplish those?

Comment: This was driving me nuts, thanks for confirming this is the expected behaviour. I need some kind of workaround to this problem. How disappointing :(